# Inner Join in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

---

**I want to put inner join of 2 tables PhieuMuonSach and
    CTPhieuMuonSach to view**

---

**PhieuMuonSach Model:**

```
[Table("PhieuMuonSach")]
public partial class PhieuMuonSach
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PhieuMuonSach()
    {
        CTPhieuMuonSach = new HashSet<CTPhieuMuonSach>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id_PhieuMuon { get; set; }

    public int? Id_DocGia { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NgayMuon { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CTPhieuMuonSach> CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public virtual TheDocGia TheDocGia { get; set; }
}
```

**CTPhieuMuonSach Model:**

```
[Table("CTPhieuMuonSach")]
public partial class CTPhieuMuonSach
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id_PhieuMuon { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id_Sach { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NgayTra { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TrangThai { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string GhiChu { get; set; }

    public virtual PhieuMuonSach PhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public virtual Sach Sach { get; set; }
}
```

**QuanLyMuonTraSach Model:**

```
 public class QuanLyMuonTraSach
{
    public PhieuMuonSach PhieuMuonSach { get; set; }
    public CTPhieuMuonSach CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }
    //public Sach Sach { get; set; }
    //public LoaiSach LoaiSach { get; set; }
}
```

**QuanLyMuonTraSachController:**

```
public ActionResult TestNe(int? id)
    {
        using (QuanLyThuVienContext Db = new QuanLyThuVienContext())
        {
            var CTPhieuMuonInnerJoinPhieuMuon = Db.CTPhieuMuonSach
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Join(Db.PhieuMuonSach, ct => ct.Id_PhieuMuon, p => p.Id_PhieuMuon, (ct, p) => new { ct, p })
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    s.p.Id_PhieuMuon,
                    s.p.Id_DocGia,
                    s.ct.Id_Sach,
                    s.p.NgayMuon,
                    s.ct.NgayTra,
                    s.ct.TrangThai,
                    s.ct.GhiChu
                }).AsQueryable();
            var data = CTPhieuMuonInnerJoinPhieuMuon.ToList();

            return View(data);

        }
    }
```

**My View:**

```
    @model  IEnumerable<CNPMNC_QLThuVien.Models.QuanLyMuonTraSach>

  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestNe";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_PhieuMuonSach.cshtml";
   }



   <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
   </p>
   <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8">
    <table class="table">
         <tr>
              <th>
                Id_Phieu
              </th>
              <th>
                Id_DocGia
              </th>
               <th>
                Id_Sach
              </th>
            <th>
                NgayMuon
            </th>
            <th>
                Ngay Tra
            </th>
            <th>
                Trang Thai
            </th>
            <th>
                Ghi Chu
            </th>


            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhieuMuonSach.Id_PhieuMuon)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhieuMuonSach.Id_DocGia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CTPhieuMuonSach.Id_Sach)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhieuMuonSach.NgayMuon)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CTPhieuMuonSach.NgayTra)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CTPhieuMuonSach.TrangThai)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CTPhieuMuonSach.GhiChu)
            </td>


            @*<td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id_PhieuMuon, idS = item.Id_Sach }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id_PhieuMuon, idS = item.Id_Sach }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id_PhieuMuon, idS = item.Id_Sach })
                </td>*@
        </tr>
    }

</table>
</
```

when I run it, error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`7[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CNPMNC_QLThuVien.Models.QuanLyMuonTraSach]'.

**Please help me to show inner join table!!!!**

Comment: Because your query generates a collection of anonymous objects (using `select new { ...` - You view expects `IEnumerable<QuanLyMuonTraSach>` so you need to pass it a collection of `QuanLyMuonTraSach`

Comment: sorry, i just learned mvc c # so still do not understand your mind! Can you give me a demo on what you say? My English is bad, you understand ^ _ ^

Comment: To match the model in the view it would be `select new QuanLyMuonTraSach { // set properties here }`